# "definition" or "defining" (of the)?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is best:

1. Defining of the settings is enabled when...
2. Defining settings is enabled when...
3. Definition of the settings is enabled when...
4. (some other form)

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Settings can be adjusted when/if....**

**Settings can be defined when...**

I think I'd go with adjust, because that implies that if you don't do anything, the default settings will be somewhat useful, maybe.  As opposed to you have to define them before you do anything.

Also, by starting out with **Settings**, you make that word more prominent.

From the word *enabled*, I suspect computer-related usage ;-)

In your above, #3, Definition of is more correct than #1, Defining of